# integer division gives different result in CPython 2.7 and Spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, division

I have encountered a quite weird case in Python.

In Spyder:

```
>>> 274/365
0.7506849315068493
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Dec 20 2013, 14:08:04) [MSC v.1700 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>>
```

However in command line it returns 0.

```
>>> 274/365
0
>>> 274/365 * 1.0
0.0
>>> 274/365.0
0.7506849315068493
```

Same version of Python.

Could anyone tell what is wrong here? Do I need to put some other options ahead of the program? This is really nauseous since my code gave weird results if I call it through command line..

Comment: What is the result of `sys.version` in the standard command-line?

Comment: '2.7.6 (default, Dec 20 2013, 14:08:04) [MSC v.1700 64 bit (AMD64)]'   same, so I didnt pasted it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spyder executes `from __future__ import division` in its console.

This is discussed at https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1646 - it looks like this will be deactivated by default to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! So I better add this line explicitly.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if this works for you then ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You either use different versions of Python (in Spyder 3.* and on command line 2.*) or in your Spyder there is automatic import for your console including

```
from __future__ import division
```

On command line for Python 2.7

```
>>> 4/3
1
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 4/3
1.3333333333333333
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 at both end. I believe it is because of the secret import. Thanks you for telling me this Easter egg!